# Looking for high dimensional integral problems in statistical physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, integration

I've currently working on a Monte Carlo Estimation of high dimensional integrals. I'm wondering if there is a list of well-studied high dimensional integral (50-100 dimensions) integrals in statistical physics I can run my experiments on.

I hope there is ground truth for such integrals so that I can know how good my estimation is.

Also, if ground truth is not available, I can experiments on certain type of integrals where its a probability distribution and I can generate true samples from.

Comment: Here's one possible integral I can think of: $\int_V \exp(-\sum_{i=1}^{50} x_i^2)\;\mathrm dV = \pi^{25}$ over $\mathbb R^{50}$.

Comment: @GodotMisogi; thanks for reply; I kind of did this experiments as it's kind of special cases of unnormalized Gaussian distribution. Is there any other come to the mind?